# Como criar chave composta no MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

Como posso criar chave composta no MongoDB e utilizar no C#?

Comment: Se pode eu não sei, mas por que alguém faria isso?

Comment: Faz um objeto como primary key que contém 2 valores, por exemplo: `{ _id : { a : 1, b: 1} }`.

Comment: É uma necessidade. Porque não faria, @LINQ ?

Comment: @fajuchem, deu certo aqui. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como mencionado por @fajuchen, nada impede que você popule `_id` com um objeto composto:

```
{
    _id: { 
        a: 'b99c514b-cb23-4b42-8710-a69db774c904',
        b: '1caf0d2f-3f03-4287-a8ed-65c77f1d0ef4'
    }
}
```

Esta é a melhor opção se você puder garantir que acesso aos documentos será sempre pela chave composta.

Caso não, talvez valha a pena considerar a criação de um índice secundário mapeado para uma propriedade com o conteúdo da chave composta:

```
{
    _id: 'ff1a5f39-bdea-4d25-b473-0a15d9602963',
    key: { 
        a: 'b99c514b-cb23-4b42-8710-a69db774c904',
        b: '1caf0d2f-3f03-4287-a8ed-65c77f1d0ef4'
    }
}
```